# Twilio add incoming call to queue and call to the agent

Tags: php, twilio

I have run in the situation where i'm handling incoming call using PHP/laravel, so when client calls to the company number the response is this method :

```
 public function respondToUser()
{
    $response = new Twiml();

    $audio_file_path = trans('ivr_file_paths.welcome');
    $response->play($audio_file_path);
    $response->redirect('/ivr/call/enqueue', ['method' => 'POST']);

    return $response;
}
```

But what I want to achieve next is to put incoming call in queue and then run the music in background if the operator (one operator /agent only) is busy, if not then connect to him.

this is what it looks like now

```
 public function enqueueCall(Request $request)
 {

  $please_wait_audio_file = trans('paths.please_wait');


  $please_wait_audio_file = trans('ivr_file_paths.please_wait');

  $response = new Twiml();

  $dial = $response->dial();

  $dial->number('+number');
  $response->enqueue('support', ['waitUrl' => $please_wait_audio_file]);

  Log::info($response);
  echo $response;
}
```

I know there is no queue right now, but this method just ends up the call..

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend you start by looking at the [`<Enqueue>` TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) which queues a caller up, followed by [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue) which you can use within `<Dial>` to pop the next user off from the queue and talk to them.

If you need anything more complicated than that, then start reading into [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter).

**edit** some example code:

Enqueue the caller and dial your agent.

```
public function enqueueCall(Request $request)
  {
  // build up the TwiML
  $please_wait_audio_file = trans('ivr_file_paths.please_wait');
  $response = new Twiml();
  $response->enqueue('support', ['waitUrl' => $please_wait_audio_file]);

  // make the call to your agent
  $client = new Client($yourTwilioAccountSid, $yourTwilioAuthToken);
  $call = $client->calls->create(
      $yourAgentNumber,
      $yourTwilioNumber,
      array("url" => "http://example.com/ivr/call/queue")
  );

  Log::info($response);
  echo $response;
}
```

When the agent connects, dial the queue:

```
public function dialQueue(Request $request)
  {
  $response = new Twiml();
  $dial = $response->dial();
  $dial->queue('support');

  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Please check the updated post. I changed few lines. but queue is not working still.

Comment: Ok, you can't nest an `<Enqueue>` inside a `<Dial>` so that's why it's not working. I'd recommend making the call to your agent using the REST API leaving the  TwiML to just put the caller into the queue.

Comment: Can you please post some example code? I can't get it working.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it shortly!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're saying here. Are you saying that the caller does not get put in the queue? Or does it just go quiet? I'm not sure what you have behind `$please_wait_audio_file` but you can add a URL that points to TwiML there, using `<Play>` or `<Say>` and looping so that the user does get music. Does that help?